# Error in adding element to the back of linked list

Tags: c++, debugging, class, linked-list

I am trying to add an element to the back of a linked list.

I am able to add the element and everything works fine on the first try but when i try to add another element, the previously added element becomes rubbish value.

The problem is solved when i replace the `LinkedList::process_example(int choice,LinkedList &set)` function in the main menu with exactly the same code in my function declaration. Can someone explain to me why????

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Node;
typedef void* VoidPtr;
typedef Node* NodePtr;
typedef char* ZodiacSign;
const int MAX=12;

struct Node
{
NodePtr next;
VoidPtr data;

};

class LinkedList
{
public:
LinkedList();

//~LinkedList();

void Addelement(VoidPtr);

void printSet();

int compareEqual(VoidPtr,VoidPtr);

void swap(int num,int x,ZodiacSign tempSign [MAX]);

void process_example(int choice);

int check_cardinality();

void Addelementfromback(VoidPtr);



private:

NodePtr head;

ZodiacSign getVP(VoidPtr);


};


int choice=1;
LinkedList set;
do {
    cout<<endl
        <<endl;

    cout<<"Wish to try the following operation?"
        <<endl
        <<"1. Add an element to set"// the function to add to back of linked list
        <<endl
        <<"2. Check an element in set"
        <<endl
        <<"3. check carinality"
        <<endl
        <<"9.  Quit"
        <<endl
        <<endl;

    cout<<"Your choice : ";
    cin>>choice;

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(200,'\n');

    set.process_example(choice);

} while (choice !=9);


void LinkedList::process_example(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout<<endl
            <<endl
            <<"Current S = ";

        this->printSet();

        cout<<"Enter an element :";

        char element [30];

        cin>>element;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(200,'\n');

        this->Addelementfromback(element);

        cout<<endl
            <<endl
            <<"Current S = ";

        this->printSet();

        break;

    case 3:
        cout<<endl
            <<endl;

        cout<<"Current Set S = ";
        set.printSet();

        cout<<endl
            <<"S has ";

        int count=this->check_cardinality();

        cout<<count
            <<" elements";
    }
}

void LinkedList::printSet()
{
    NodePtr temp = head;

    cout<<"{ ";

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << getVP (temp -> data) << " , ";
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    cout<<" } ";
    cout << endl;
}

void LinkedList::Addelementfromback(VoidPtr horoscope)
{
    NodePtr temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    NodePtr element = new Node;
    element->data=horoscope;
    element->next=NULL;
    temp->next=element;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this question may be helpful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005284/insert-to-sorted-position-linked-list

Comment: Seeing the definition of `LinkedList` would likely help; not just a couple of member functions. But right of the top, what to you think this: `NodePtr temp = head; while (temp->next != NULL)... temp->next = element;` does when **`head`** is NULL? In other words, how does that code behave, and where does it write the new element pointer when the new element is the *first* element?

Comment: Could this be because while calling `process_example` you are passing the value like
    set.process_example(choice, set)
but in the method `process_example` you are getting the address of `set` object due to the "&" (address of) operator?

Also I don't understand the logic behind calling the method/ function `process_example` using `set.process_example` and then passing the `set` variable to it again as one of its parameters. You could always access the `set` variable in the method `process_example` using the `this` operator.

Comment: I have added the defination of LinkedList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As WhozCraig already mentioned you need to add the following lines to the constructor

```
Head = NULL;
```

and then you can add the something like this to the beginning of function Addelementfromback

```
If(Head == NULL)
{
     Head = new Node;
     Head->data = horoscope;
     Head->next = NULL;
     return;
}
```

you also need to change the following line in LinkedList::process_example

```
 char elements[30];
```

to

```
 char* elements = new char[30];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem still exist

Comment: @Computernerd Found one more problem and has add this to my solution. Your program works for me with this change

Comment: You are a genius thanks so much. Can you explain why char* element= new char [30] works???

Comment: @Computernerd well previously as soon as you left the scope of process_example the memory was released but with new you allocate the memory on the heap and it will only be freed when you tell it to. So now it is up to you to find proper place to free the memory (delete) otherwise will you have a nice memory leek ;-)

Comment: Can people help me up this answer, i would up this like 10 times if i could.